# Spring Integration Aggregator or Router the right pattern?

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I have a szenario which seems at the first glance like a perfect fit for using a Spring Integration Aggregator:

A Large amount of PDF Report's are produced currently. These are printed via Printrequests to a JMS Queue. A Print Server accepts client sockets with print requests.

In order to achieve a certain about of "fairness" in terms of load, we would like to aggregate the print requests for the same printer. And then send the aggregated requests to the Print Server. We have completness criterias for the aggregated requests, basically the number of pdf produced for a "Batch" and also have a unique key per "Batch" of requested PDF reports. The aggregated requests would then be "sent" via a service activator to the Print Server via the same client Socket. So basically we are  taking the approach described in Spring Integration Documentation.

The problem : the reports will only start printing, when the last pdf report of the "Batch" is produced, which seems to create quite a bottle neck.

Ideally we could start to print as soon as the first Message of a MessageGroup arrives and effectively aggregate the results of a print request.

I have been thinking  to achieve this with a custom MessageStore, where the

```
public void add(Message<?> messageToAdd)
```

Method implements the additional logic call the Printer Server and actually aggregating the responses of the Server.  Something like a "active" MessageStore.

But then the add Method of custom MessageStore could be a "big" Bottleneck... blocking each add to a  "active" MessageStore... and also seems like the wrong metapher: Store vs Processing something.

Is the Aggregator the right approach for these requirements?

Or should i should go more for the approach a dynamic router channel decribed in the [Dynamic Ftp Spring Integration Example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/advanced/dynamic-ftp)

With a child(s) / parent applicationscontext for each "Batch" of print requests?
There the lifecycle of the childs applicationcontext is not quite so clear to me.

Ideally i would be able to manage all context's - childs and parents with JMX as described in [the Monitoring Example of Spring Integration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/intermediate/monitoring)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have some [Buttered cat paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buttered_cat_paradox).

You want to minimize Network load via aggregated request, but at the same time you want to send each item from aggregator to print.

You should decide for yourself what is really your goal.

Maybe you just need a `router` which logic will be based on some `key` to delegate to the proper channel for particular socket to send to the Print Server?

Otherwise sorry: your problem isn't clear...

Comment: I see your point ;-) ....just looking for the right pattern and abstractions using Spring Integration,  which is by the way great!

Comment: It's not so much that i want to minimize Network load, but group requests, send them on a standing Connection and formost to have a deterministic criteria to when to close the Connection again. There i believe the Aggreator, would be a perfect fit, But yes, i wait until the aggregation is complete.  Which is not the case with the router approach as you suggest and which i am following now, But here i don't see how i can deterministically close the a child context with a channel socket per socket, based on Message Input.?

Comment: That sounds like a different story... And it is fully unclear to me why you have to have child context per socket. You have strict number of Print Servers, so just configure `<int-tcp:connection-factrory mode="client">` for each of them and corresponding channel adapter to communicate via client socket. You can close and reconnect by some external event or idle interval.

Comment: Sorry, yes i was totally unclear. The problem domain is batch printing in large volumnes. We have actually exactly one print server. But would like have a standing connection on a printer (batch) basis and send request for the same printer via the same standing connection. Eventually the "batch" for a printer is finished.

Comment: So, forget aggregator and do "batch" manually, but still utilize router for proper socket to send item

Comment: Best thanks, that confirms the approach i have taken, based on the  Dynamic Ftp Spring Integration Example. Concerning the aggregator:  I was thinking that i maybe could aggregate the results in the child context and that way close the socket criteria based.

Comment: Makes sense. But still each item is sent to the print server separately. And yes, you can aggregate responses to reach some state and produce a report. Or even just close the socket as  you are talking about.